# How convert dates to dates range by condition (postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql, gaps-and-islands

Please help with the request, there is such data: you need to break this data into intervals, in the status column, so that approximately it looks like this:

[image: data_image_example]

```
client| date_start        | date_end          | status
-------------------------------------------------------
1     | 01.06.2019 0:00:00| 01.06.2019 0:02:00| 2
1     | 01.06.2019 0:02:00| 01.06.2019 0:04:00| 1
1     | 01.06.2019 0:04:00| 01.06.2019 0:05:00| 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a form of gaps-and-islands with a twist.  You can identify the adjacent rows using a difference of row numbers.  Then aggregate and use `lead()` to get the end time:

```
select client, status, min(time) as starttime,
       lead(min(time)) over (partition by client order by min(time)) as endtime
from  (select t.*,
              row_number() over (partition by client order by time) as seqnum,
              row_number() over (partition by client, status order by time) as seqnum_s
       from t
      ) t
group by (seqnum - seqnum_s), status, client;
```

Comment: if I have a fixed interval of 1 minute, and suddenly a segment break, how can I take this into mind?

Comment: @ivani . . . I would suggest asking a new question with appropriate  sample data and desired results.  Please add the data as *text tables* in the question.  A db fiddle of some sort is also helpful.